# Are $P(A,B) = P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A \cap B)$?

Tags: probability, notation

Sorry if this is a simple question but it's important for me to ensure all of these are equal:

$$P(A,B) = P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A \cap B)$$

Also

$$P(A|B,C) = P(A|B \cap C)$$

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @Yanko: Is this true too : `P(A|B,C) = P(A|B^C) 
`

Comment: @Hasani yes....

Comment: @Hasani No, that second equality you listed in the comments is probably false. $\mathbb P(A \mid B, C)$ is $\mathbb P(A \mid B \text{ and } C)$, whereas $\mathbb P (A \mid B^c)$ is almost certainly $\mathbb P(A \mid \text{not } B)$.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery My guess is that `P(A|B^C)` was an attempt to write $P(A \mid B \land C)$ or $P(A \mid B \cap C)$ rather than $P(A \mid B^C)$

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: As Henry mentioned I was trying to write `P(A∣B∩C) ` instead of `P(A|B^C)`

Comment: Ah, okay -- I understand now.